# how to check if an object element is empty

Tags: vue.js

I have a vue form and I am trying gather the data into an object, But when one object element is empty then Id want that field to be destroy'd.

this is my input field:

```
 <input v-model="fields.title" >
```

my data:

```
 data() {
        return {
            fields: {},
        }
    },
```

Basically right now what happens, is when I write something in my field, it creates `title: 'data'` and if i delete the text inside then that element still exists there so I am left with `title: ''`, but I want it to be deleted if its empty.

I can recreate this like this:

```
computed: {
       destroyFieldWhenEmpty() {
           if (this.fields.title === ''){
               this.$delete(this.fields, 'title')
           }
```

But now If i have a lot of fields, I have to re-write that if statement for each input.

Thus, How could i go by doing this better?

Comment: why are you doing that? what's the specific use case?

Comment: `destroyFieldWhenEmpty` is a misuse of computed props, as it's seemingly used only to delete `fields.title`, but computed props are supposed to return something (to be used elsewhere in the component) and should not have side effects.

Comment: @BoussadjraBrahim So basically, I want to change a class of one of my div's When Data is inserted into any of the fields, to do this I'd need to check if the fields object is empty, and change the class based on that.

Comment: could you show how are you doing that?

Answer (score 1):

**- Use lodash [isEmpty()](https://lodash.com/docs/4.17.15#isEmpty) function**

```
_.isEmpty({}) // true
_.isEmpty({title: 'title'}) // false
```

---

**- Use [Object.keys()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/keys).length**

```
const obj = {...}
```

If `obj` is empty, `Object.keys(obj).length` equals to 0.

Answer (score 0):

So far I've got your problem, you're trying to delete an object from an array. if so you can filter data with your own business logic like this

```
const restFields = this.fields.filter(field => field.title.length > 0)
```

Comment: `fields` is an object, not an array.

Comment: @tony19 did you, did you try adding `v-if="fields.title"` to hide any vue component. or if you want to delete key from an object then try `delete this.fields.title` . Actually there too many ways to do it but not clear what is your logic there.